# Instantly updating conditionalPanels when condition has changed

Tags: r, shiny

I have two conditionalPanels that I want to change based on the user's selection in a `selectInput`. However, the conditionalPanels only update when the user clicks the `submitButton`. This leads to a terrible UI functionality where you first have to submit values before you can see the correct labels for what you are submitting. Below is my code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      selectInput("type", "Type", c(1, 2)),
      conditionalPanel(
        "input.type == 1",
        "Test 1"
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        "input.type == 2",
        "Test 2"
      ),
      
      submitButton("Add", icon = NULL, width = NULL)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried the same thing with observeEvent and renderUI, but it still only updates when you click submit. Is there any way to make the change instant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `actionButton` instead.

```
actionButton("Add", label="Add", icon=NULL, width=NULL)
```

Why?  Because "Apps that include a submit button do not automatically update their outputs when inputs change, rather they wait until the user explicitly clicks the submit button. The use of `submitButton` is generally discouraged in favor of the more versatile `actionButton()`" - see https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/submitButton.html